# PHPWord - Can't read docx file

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I'm trying to read a docx file using PHPWord, but i'm getting the following error. I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere:

> *PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with message '"Word2007" is
>   not a valid Reader.'*

This is the PHP code to load the file:

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filepath1); 
$xmlWriter = PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure the autoload is working? what's the result of "new PhpOffice\PhpWord\Reader\Word2017();"?

Comment: `$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');` -> add a backslash, I'd say

Comment: @Maria - That didn't work but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, so depending on your PHPWord version, the library is not able to create the Reader in /PhpWord/IOFactory.php::createObject(). so have you included the autoloader correctly (as @troosan said)? Maybe edit your question with a full code example :)

Answer (score -2):

```html
Method 1:-

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader("Word2007");
$phpWord = $reader->load($file);
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, "PDF");
$writer->save('example.pdf');

For more info visit :- https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it